# TikZ : decoration and quotes positioning in a graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

There're some positioning conflicts here for the graph to be more legible :

- the 2 arrows in the center (from C1 to v4 and C3 to v1) : they should be placed for example at `pos=.48`.
- some numbers over the edges should be placed at a different position, for example `pos=.33`

Is there an automated way to obtain a more legible graph?

If not, how can I add 2 more optional parameters for the style : `decoration` position and `quotes` position?

I'd appreciate also any input to improve the `style` definitions.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm, convert={density=600, outext=.png}]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.markings, quotes}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        > = Stealth,
        vertex/.style = {shape=circle, draw, fill=black, inner sep=2pt}, % <---
        edge/.style = {color=#1, thick, % <---
            decoration={markings,
                mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}},
            },
            postaction={decorate}},
        edge/.default=gray,
        every edge quotes/.style = {font=\scriptsize, inner sep=1.5pt, 
            pos=0.4, sloped, auto=} % <---
        ]
        \node [vertex, label=left:$C_1$] (s1) at (0, 6) {};
        \node [vertex, label=left:$C_2$] (s2) at (0, 3) {};
        \node [vertex, label=left:$C_3$] (s3) at (0, 0) {};
        
        \node [vertex, label=right:$v_1$] (v1) at (6, 6) {};
        \node [vertex, label=right:$v_2$] (v2) at (6, 4) {};
        \node [vertex, label=right:$v_3$] (v3) at (6, 2) {};
        \node [vertex, label=right:$v_4$] (v4) at (6, 0) {};
        %
        \draw [edge] (s1) to ["$8$"] (v1);
        \draw [edge=red] (s1) to ["$6$"] (v2);
        \draw [edge=red] (s1) to ["$10$"] (v3);
        \draw [edge] (s1) to ["$9$"] (v4);
        
        \draw [edge=red] (s2) to ["$9$"] (v1);
        \draw [edge] (s2) to ["$12$"] (v2);
        \draw [edge=red] (s2) to ["$13$"] (v3);
        \draw [edge] (s2) to ["$7$"] (v4);
        
        \draw [edge] (s3) to ["$14$"] (v1);
        \draw [edge=red] (s3) to ["$9$"] (v2);
        \draw [edge] (s3) to ["$16$"] (v3);
        \draw [edge=red] (s3) to ["$5$"] (v4);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As this is not an answer to  the exact question, I would suggest to place quotes at `pos=0.25` and arrows at `pos=0.85`. That doesn't make a perfect graph, I have to admit, but it makes it legible at least. On a visual perspective, I don't think that placing arrows at different positions depending on the edges would be less attractive.

Comment: That's actually really good! I like the quotes at `pos=0.25`, it makes the information very legible. I placed the arrows at `pos=0.72`. Quite neat!

Comment: So I'll make it an answer. Maybe someone (Zarko?) would come with a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to save the overall appearance of the graph and not create misplacements of the arrows, I suggest to only play with the `pos=...` values here.

[image: decoration and quotes adjustments]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm, convert={density=600, outext=.png}]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.markings, quotes}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        > = Stealth,
        vertex/.style = {shape=circle, draw, fill=black, inner sep=2pt}, % <---
        edge/.style = {color=#1, thick, % <---
            decoration={markings,
                mark= at position 0.85 with {\arrow{>}},
            },
            postaction={decorate}},
        edge/.default=gray,
        every edge quotes/.style = {font=\scriptsize, inner sep=1.5pt, 
            pos=0.25, sloped, auto} % <---
        ]
        \node [vertex, label=left:$C_1$] (s1) at (0, 6) {};
        \node [vertex, label=left:$C_2$] (s2) at (0, 3) {};
        \node [vertex, label=left:$C_3$] (s3) at (0, 0) {};
        
        \node [vertex, label=right:$v_1$] (v1) at (6, 6) {};
        \node [vertex, label=right:$v_2$] (v2) at (6, 4) {};
        \node [vertex, label=right:$v_3$] (v3) at (6, 2) {};
        \node [vertex, label=right:$v_4$] (v4) at (6, 0) {};
        %
        \draw [edge] (s1) to ["$8$"] (v1);
        \draw [edge=red] (s1) to ["$6$"] (v2);
        \draw [edge=red] (s1) to ["$10$"] (v3);
        \draw [edge] (s1) to ["$9$"] (v4);
        
        \draw [edge=red] (s2) to ["$9$"] (v1);
        \draw [edge] (s2) to ["$12$"] (v2);
        \draw [edge=red] (s2) to ["$13$"] (v3);
        \draw [edge] (s2) to ["$7$"] (v4);
        
        \draw [edge] (s3) to ["$14$"] (v1);
        \draw [edge=red] (s3) to ["$9$"] (v2);
        \draw [edge] (s3) to ["$16$"] (v3);
        \draw [edge=red] (s3) to ["$5$"] (v4);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```